# How do I count the occurencies of a word in csv file under conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, count

I have a data.csv file as such (where data are words)

```
data
data1|data2|data3
data1|data2
data1|data4|data6
data2|data3
data4|data5|data6
data4
data5|data7
```

I want to read how many times data1 (for example) is present **when** data2 is present. So when and how many times in the rows two data coexist, as I want to form relationships between them. I am aware of the counter method but I am not interested in just counting instances of the data.

How do I solve this? Do I create a data frame with pd or do I use a list?

(edit:max number of columns in the data.csv is 6)

The desired output would be something like:

```
data1-data2: 2
data1-data3: 1
data1-data4: 1
data1-data5: 0 
etc
```

saved into a CSV file

Comment: Hi Steven, what have you tried so far? Could you include your current approach?

Comment: I don't have something to show for tbh. I tried to convert my csv into a dataframe of 6 columns then make that into a 2d list and use a condition to read it, but it failed spectacularly. I don't have experience parsing data so I came here.

Comment: the answers below that use `itertools` are quite elegant

Comment: Could you provide a full desired output of this sample data? There is a lot of ambiguity as to what correlations you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I see how it seems confusing. For example: data4-data5 result should be 1. For the data5-data4 the desired result should also be 1 despite not being a row containing this combination in that order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is very ambiguous, hence so many different answers. I assume here you mean to count the combinations of the first column and any of the following columns.

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
  for line in reader:
    if line[0]:
      for fragment in line[1:]:
        entry = line[0] + '-' + fragment
        counter.update({entry: 1})

print(counter)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'data1-data2': 2, 'data1-data3': 1, 'data1-data4': 1, 'data1-data6': 1, 'data2-data3': 1, 'data4-data5': 1, 'data4-data6': 1, 'data5-data7': 1})
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

Assuming you want any non-zero combinations of existing data fields:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations

counter = Counter()
with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
  for line in reader:
    counter.update(combinations(line, 2))

print(counter)
```

Output:

```
Counter({('data1', 'data2'): 2, ('data2', 'data3'): 2, ('data4', 'data6'): 2, ('data1', 'data3'): 1, ('data1', 'data4'): 1, ('data1', 'data6'): 1, ('data4', 'data5'): 1, ('data5', 'data6'): 1, ('data5', 'data7'): 1})
```

---

**EDIT 2:**
Assuming you want each data cell combined with each other data cell including those relationships that do not show up anywhere on the same line:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations

counter = Counter()
unique = set()
with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
  for line in reader:
    unique.update(line)
    counter.update(combinations(line, 2))
counter.update({entry: 0 for entry in combinations(unique, 2)})
print(counter)
```

Output:

```
Counter({('data1', 'data2'): 2, ('data2', 'data3'): 2, ('data4', 'data6'): 2, ('data1', 'data3'): 1, ('data1', 'data4'): 1, ('data1', 'data6'): 1, ('data4', 'data5'): 1, ('data5', 'data6'): 1, ('data5', 'data7'): 1, ('data7', 'data5'): 0, ('data7', 'data2'): 0, ('data7', 'data4'): 0, ('data7', 'data6'): 0, ('data7', 'data1'): 0, ('data7', 'data'): 0, ('data7', 'data3'): 0, ('data5', 'data2'): 0, ('data5', 'data4'): 0, ('data5', 'data1'): 0, ('data5', 'data'): 0, ('data5', 'data3'): 0, ('data2', 'data4'): 0, ('data2', 'data6'): 0, ('data2', 'data1'): 0, ('data2', 'data'): 0, ('data4', 'data1'): 0, ('data4', 'data'): 0, ('data4', 'data3'): 0, ('data6', 'data1'): 0, ('data6', 'data'): 0, ('data6', 'data3'): 0, ('data1', 'data'): 0, ('data', 'data3'): 0})
```

Comment: Sorry for not phrasing it better. I actually care for combinations of any kind between 2 data. That's what I meant by "coexist". The order of columns is irrelevant but thank you for your solution!

Comment: @Steven This was a fun exercise! I added other samples based on all the things you could have meant :D

Comment: Glad you liked it. By the way, is it possible to skip the header of the file?

Comment: @Steven are you talking about the header in your CSV file? That really depends on whether you have a valid header or not. The sample data in your post is not having a valid header - it would need to define a name for each column. If you just want to skip the first line of the file, you can add `next(csvfile)` right before initiating the reader.

Comment: I just wanted to skip the first line (worked like a charm) thx

Answer (score 2):

Let's try with `get_dummies` and `combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
d = df['data'].str.get_dummies('|')

dct = {}
for x, y in combinations(g, r=2):
    dct[f'{x}:{y}'] = d[[x, y]].eq(1).all(1).sum()

# or with dict comprehension
# {'{}:{}'.format(*v): d[[*v]].eq(1).all(1).sum() for v in combinations(g, r=2)}
```

**Details:**

First read the `csv` file as `pandas` dataframe:

```
print(df)
                data
0  data1|data2|data3
1        data1|data2
2  data1|data4|data6
3        data2|data3
4  data4|data5|data6
5              data4
6        data5|data7
```

Encode the values in `data` as dummy/indicator columns:

```
print(d)
   data1  data2  data3  data4  data5  data6  data7
0      1      1      1      0      0      0      0
1      1      1      0      0      0      0      0
2      1      0      0      1      0      1      0
3      0      1      1      0      0      0      0
4      0      0      0      1      1      1      0
5      0      0      0      1      0      0      0
6      0      0      0      0      1      0      1
```

generate `combinations` of indicator columns and use `dict` to store their frequency of occurrence together:

---

```
print(dct)
{'data1:data2': 2,
 'data1:data3': 1,
 'data1:data4': 1,
 'data1:data5': 0,
 'data1:data6': 1,
 'data1:data7': 0,
 'data2:data3': 2,
  ...
  ...
 'data5:data7': 1,
 'data6:data7': 0}
```

Comment: Nice and elegant solution. However, you might want to expand that dict comprehension, since it's arguably hard to read and understand, especially given this is a site about helping less experienced devs and not code golf.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Thanks, for your suggestion :)..but IMHO after expanding  its just more lines of code....

Comment: Extra lines of code are a good thing if they ease the understanding and make the code easier to edit.

Comment: It showed NameError: name 'g' is not defined @ShubhamSharma

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Not a problem..edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
import itertools

with open('yourfile.csv') as f:
    l=f.readlines()

l=[i[:-1] for i in l[:-1]] + [l[-1]] #remove '\n' at the end

res={}

for i in l:
    temp=i.split('|')
    pairs=[k for k in itertools.combinations(temp, 2)]
    for j in pairs:
        if j in res:
            res[j]+=1
        elif j[::-1] in res:
            res[j[::-1]]+=1
        else:
            res[j]=1
```

Output:

```
>>>print(res)

{('data1', 'data2'): 2, ('data1', 'data3'): 1, ('data2', 'data3'): 2, ('data1', 'data4'): 1, ('data1', 'data6'): 1, ('data4', 'data6'): 2, ('data4', 'data5'): 1, ('data5', 'data6'): 1, ('data5', 'data7'): 1}
```

If you want the pairs that have 0 occurences, you can do the following:

```
s={i for j in res.keys() for i in j}

allpairs=[i for i in itertools.combinations(s,2)]

for i in allpairs:
    if i not in res and (i[1], i[0]) not in res:
        res[i]=0
```